# unordered_set of TCHAR* requirements?

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I want to use data structure that serves like .Net HashSet, I tried to use unordered_set with the default hashing method and custom comparer as follows:

```
struct comparer
    {
        bool operator()( const TCHAR* first,const TCHAR* second) const
        {   
            return _tcscmp((TCHAR*)first,(TCHAR*)second) == 0;
        }
    };

    typedef unordered_set<const TCHAR*,hash<const TCHAR*>,comparer> HashSet;
```

the problem is when I tried to use the HashtSet to find specific key (using `find` method) that is I just added using `insert` it returns `HashSet::end()`!!

Could you explain what is the problem?
I'm using VC++ under VS2010

Comment: Why do you need to cast away the consts for `_tcscmp()`? That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Uninformed guess: `hash<>` is hashing the pointer value not the string. But I don't know the TR1 classes.

Comment: @Rup: I thought that but I want to get sure!

Comment: @Rup: it is a copy paste problem from another code! sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `hash` here is `std::hash`, there is no specialization of `std::hash` for `char*` or `wchar*` other than the generic specialization for any pointer type, that hashes based on the pointer value.

So, if you want to use `TCHAR*` as a hash key, with the hash based on the string contents instead of the pointer value, you'll need to supply a different hash functor class.

There are specializations of `std::hash` for `string` and `wstring`, that I think you could use if you pick the right one according to `_UNICODE`. I say "I think" because TCHAR* should just convert to `string` or `wstring`, but if I've missed something then you could write a simple wrapper.

If you were going to do either of those, though, then you could just as well use `string` or `wstring` as the hash key, since everything will need to be converted for hashing anyway. This will also allow you to add strings to your unordered_set without having to keep them hanging around until they're removed. With your code above, I imagine it's a nuisance adding anything other than string literals to the set.

If you're worried about speed, and not worried about managing the strings, then pick your favourite string hashing algorithm and apply it to the string data.

Comment: It's quite common to typedef a `tstring` as a `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`. This will equal either `std::string` or `std::wstring`, and therefore you get the appropriate `hash` for free.